# matlab - Find a bounding box which can cover a character in image

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

An image represents a Korean character. All values of the image are composed of 0 or 255.

Then I wanna get a bounding box which can perfectly cover the character in the image.

For example:

**Input image**

[image]

**Output image**(What I want is to get the vertices of the red box.)

[image]

I have an idea to do this but I think that is not good:

**Step 1.** Find the leftmost and uppermost index in the image, say *(l, up)*

**Step 2.** Find the rightmost and lowermost index in the image, say *(r, low)*

**Step 3.** Then the square(*bounding box*) whose one of vertices is *(l, up)* and *(r, low)* can cover a character in an image.

Is there a good idea or matlab library for this?

Comment: Yes, this works. But usually you have several characters in the same image, and possibly extra dots, and this approach is insufficient.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you know any good library for this?

Comment: The "standard" answer is Tesseract, but this package is highly sophisticated and it could scare you. What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: Ultimately, I will do text recognition using matlab, but before that, I think I have to get bounding boxes for each characters in image.

Comment: @YvesDaoust After getting boxes, I will do text recognition(more exactly character recognition) for each boxes.

Comment: I guess that Matlab has a toolbox for this, but I don't know more. Any OCR package will handle the segmentation of the characters, you won't have to take care yourself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust May I know the terminology of this in computer vision?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you. I will examine that.

Answer (score 0):

Even without the Matlab image processing toolbox, you could extract the left,right,top,bottom boundary indices of the input image using [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#buf0c2r-8).
Assuming the image is a binary matrix (logical 1 or 0) called "input":

```
leftBoundary = find(input,1,'first');
rightBoundary = find(input,1,'last');
topBoundary = find(input',1,'first');
BotBoundary = find(input',1,'last');
```

Keep in mind these are linear indices. You can use other summoning methods of find to get normal subscripts if needed

> [row,col] = find(___)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the function [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to find [logical indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) for the rows and columns that contain any part of your character, then [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the row and column indices of the extremities:

```
img = imread('Y2ZIW.png');  % Load RGB image you posted
bw = ~im2bw(img);           % Convert to binary and negate
rowIndex = any(bw, 2);      % N-by-1 logical index for rows
colIndex = any(bw, 1);      % 1-by-N logical index for columns

boundBox = [find(colIndex, 1, 'first') find(rowIndex, 1, 'first'); ...
            find(colIndex, 1, 'last')  find(rowIndex, 1, 'last')];
```

This gives us the following 2-by-2 matrix for `boundBox`, which we can use as indices into your image to crop just the region containing the character:

```
boundBox =

    71    57    % Left and upper corner index
   214   180    % Right and lower corner index

subRegion = bw(boundBox(1, 2):boundBox(2, 2), boundBox(1, 1):boundBox(2, 1));
imshow(subRegion);
```

And here's the plot of the cropped region:

[image]

If you want a minimum one-pixel border around your cropped region, you can modify the calculation for `boundBox` like so:

```
boundBox = [find(colIndex, 1, 'first')-1 find(rowIndex, 1, 'first')-1; ...
            find(colIndex, 1, 'last')+1  find(rowIndex, 1, 'last')+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I1 = imread('Y2ZIW.png') ;
I = rgb2gray(I1) ;
[y,x] = find(I==0) ;
%% Bounding box
x0 = min(x) ; x1 = max(x) ;
y0 = min(y) ; y1 = max(y) ;
B = abs(x1-x0) ;
L = abs(y1-y0) ;

BB = [x0 y0 ; x0 y0+L ; x0+B y0+L ; x0+B y0 ; x0 y0] ;

imshow(I1) ;
hold on
plot(BB(:,1),BB(:,2),'r')
```